# Count and divide number on rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the following dataset

```
1, Nike
2, Adidas 
3, oasis
4, reebok
5, puma
6, airjordan
```

for each 2 rows affect them to A,and so on

```
A, 1, Nike
A, 2, Adidas
B, 3, oasis
B, 4, reebok
C, 5, puma
C, 6, airjordan
```

Comment: dba2015 just one question what happens when you have exhausted the 26 characters in the alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you looking for:

You will need to use [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql)

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @Shoes TABLE ( ShoesId INT, Brand VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Shoes
VALUES
(1, 'Nike'),
(2, 'Adidas' ),
(3, 'oasis'),
(4, 'reebok'),
(5, 'puma'),
(6, 'airjordan')
```

Query:

```
SELECT CHAR(ASCII('A') + DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY (ShoesId%2) + ShoesId -1) - 1), 
      * 
FROM @Shoes
```

Results:

[image]